# Button calls function depending where came from

Tags: angular

I have a component called Header, and inside i have a "create" and "Search" button, this header it's in customer, products, sales pages. My question is how can i execute a create and search function for each page.

Do i have to create 3 create button component for each page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an event emitter:

```
export class ChildComponent {
    @Output() notifyParent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
    sendNotification() {
        this.notifyParent.emit('Some value to send to the parent');
    }
}
```

Parent component html:

```
<child-component (notifyParent)="parentMethod()"></child-component>
```